# Displaying every nth label on the x-axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to display weather data with ChartJS, but I'm having trouble setting up the x-axis with the correct labels.

The data I have ranges over multiple years and is an temperature average for every month of the year. Depending on which location you want the data from, there could be only 2-3 years of data or there could be 30-40 years of data. The labels on the x-axis will blend into each other the more data there is making it unreadable. How would I go about displaying only a fraction of the labels?

I tried using a callback function like this:

```
const response = await fetch('/get_specific_station_data', options);
const data = await response.json(); 

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart' + marker_id).getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: data.labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: data.title,
            data: data.data,
            borderWidth: 1,
            spanGaps: true
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    userCallback: function(item, index) {
                        let parts = item.split(" ");
                        if(parts[0] === "Januar" || parts[0] === "Juni") {
                            console.log(item);
                            return item;
                        }
                    },
                    autoSkip: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

But for some reason this will only display all labels starting with January and June is nowhere to be seen. Console logging the item shows that June is there though.

Labels could look like this:

```
['Januar 2014',    'Februar 2014', 'März 2014',     'April 2014',
'Mai 2014',       'Juni 2014',    'Juli 2014',     'August 2014',
'September 2014', 'Oktober 2014', 'November 2014', 'Dezember 2014',
'Januar 2015',    'Februar 2015', 'März 2015',     'April 2015',
'Mai 2015',       'Juni 2015',    'Juli 2015',     'August 2015',
'September 2015', 'Oktober 2015', 'November 2015', 'Dezember 2015',
'Januar 2016',    'Februar 2016', 'März 2016',     'April 2016',
'Mai 2016',       'Juni 2016',    'Juli 2016',     'August 2016',
'September 2016', 'Oktober 2016', 'November 2016', 'Dezember 2016',
'Januar 2017',    'Februar 2017', 'März 2017',     'April 2017',
'Mai 2017',       'Juni 2017',    'Juli 2017',     'August 2017',
'September 2017', 'Oktober 2017', 'November 2017', 'Dezember 2017',
'Januar 2018',    'Februar 2018', 'März 2018',     'April 2018',
'Mai 2018',       'Juni 2018',    'Juli 2018',     'August 2018',
'September 2018', 'Oktober 2018', 'November 2018', 'Dezember 2018',
'Januar 2019',    'Februar 2019', 'März 2019',     'April 2019',
'Mai 2019',       'Juni 2019',    'Juli 2019',     'August 2019',
'September 2019', 'Oktober 2019', 'November 2019', 'Dezember 2019',
'Januar 2020',    'Februar 2020', 'März 2020',     'April 2020',
'Mai 2020',       'Juni 2020',    'Juli 2020',     'August 2020',
'September 2020', 'Oktober 2020', 'November 2020', 'Dezember 2020']
```

And corresponding data could look like this:

```
[13.1, 11.9, 18.5, 19.8, 25.7, 25.2, 34.6, 28.7, 23.3,
21,   17,   11.5, 11.4, 9.3,  11.5, 14.7, 22.1, 28.4,
31.7, 27.6, 19.6, 17.3, 17.7, 15.3, 13.7, 11.4, 14,
15.8, 25.7, 23.8, 32.5, 30,   29.6, 18.7, 14.3, 10.8,
9.4,  12.1, null, 17.4, 31,   27.5, 31.1, 24.5, 22.5,
23.6, 14.9, 10.9, 12.7, 8.3,  14.3, 27.3, 26.3, 25.7,
34.5, 30.1, 22,   25.1, 16.3, 12,   10.1, 16.2, 14,
24.9, 18.1, 31.4, 34.8, 30.4, 24.8, 18.7, 14.1, 12.2,
12.4, 13.1, 11.6, null, null, null, null, null, null,
null, null, null]
```

Comment: i think, u need to add more code and data to describe.

Comment: I've added some more code and data. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the maximum number of ticks and gridlines to show on the `xAxis` using the option [`ticks.maxTicksLimit`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#tick-configuration-options).

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      maxTicksLimit: 8
    }
  }]
```