# chartjs - display nth string X-axis label?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am trying to display every `nth label` on the `x-axis` in Chartjs based on the length of the labels. I saw a similar question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654790/displaying-every-nth-label-on-the-x-axis) but the answer doesn't work for me. I went through the documentation for [tick-configuration-options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#tick-configuration-options) and wasn't able to make it work.

Example code:

```
const labels = ['11-02-2022', '11-01-2022', '30-01-2022', '11-20-2022']

const options = {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
          xAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                  maxTicksLimit: 3   # Once this works I want to make it conditional i.e. if length == 10 display 10/2
              }
          }]
      },
    interaction: {
      intersect: false
    },
    animations:animation,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      },
    },
  };
```

Would be great if someone can give a little explanation on what exactly I should have checked to fix the problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html

basically, you set the ticks value.  You use a ternary to decide when to show, e.g.

```
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    // Only show if n'th
                    callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                        return index%3 ? value : '';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```